# How to count duplicate entries of a vector in C++

Tags: c++, armadillo

I'm using Armadillo to do linear algebra calculation in C++.

For example, there is a

```
vector a = (1,1,2,2,0,2,1,0)
```

I wish return a matrix

```
(0, 2) //means 0 shows 2 times in the vector
(1, 3) //1 shows 3 times
(2, 3) //2 shows 3 times
```

Is there any function can fulfill such job?

Comment: @JohnBupit but better use `map`

Comment: @Lol4t0 Indeed. I didn't read the question through.

Comment: This is easily doable using a combination of [unique()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#unique) and [hist()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#hist).  See my detailed answer below.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in comments you could use a `std::map` to collect the results.  Then you can convert to a matrix as you see fit.  You could skip the map step and use a matrix directly if it's already pre-initialised with the rows you're after.

As for a function to do this, you can use `std::for_each` from `<algorithm>` along with a lambda expression, although it seems overkill when a loop would be fine.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v{1,1,2,2,0,2,1,0};
    map<int,int> dup;

    for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), [&dup]( int val ){ dup[val]++; } );

    for( auto p : dup ) {
        cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, we can see the `for_each` to do the job, and the *for range* to display :-) .

Comment: An alternative to `for_each` would be `for (auto x : v) ++dup[x];`

Comment: @Jarod42 yep, bases covered =)

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution, using only [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net) functions, and a C++11 compiler:

```
vec a = {1,1,2,2,0,2,1,0};  // vec holds elements of type 'double'

vec b = unique(a);

uvec c = hist(a,b);  // uvec holds unsigned integers

mat X(b.n_rows, 2);

X.col(0) = b;
X.col(1) = conv_to<vec>::from(c);

X.print("X:");
```

Explanation:

- vec b = [unique(a)](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#unique) creates a vector containing the unique elements of *a*, sorted in ascending order
- uvec c = [hist(a,b)](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#hist) creates a histogram of counts of elements in *a*, using *b* as the bin centers
- [conv_to<vec>::from(c)](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#conv_to) converts *c* (vector with unsigned integers) to the same vector type as *a*